# Multiplication Property of Z-Transform

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-transformations, z-transform

I have searched a lot online and have yet to find anything that proves the [multiplication property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties) of the z-transform ie

$$ x_1[n]x_2[n] \iff \frac{1}{2 \pi j} \oint X_1(u)X_2(\frac{z}{u})u^{-1}du $$

The operation seems very different to the continuous domain counterpart for laplace transforms. Is a knowledge of Complex Analysis necessary to understand this?

Comment: And yes, some complex analysis is needed.

Comment: Thank you for that, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, because the paths of integration below are incorrect. However, it illustrates one approach:

\begin{eqnarray}
{1 \over 2 \pi i}\int_C (\int_C \hat{x}(w) \hat{y}({ z \over w}) w^{-1} dw) z^{n-1} dz &=& {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_C \hat{x}(w)(\int_C \hat{y}({ z \over w}) z^{n-1} dz)  w^{-1} dw \\
&=& {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_C \hat{x}(w)(\int_C \hat{y}({ z \over w}) z^{n-1} {1 \over w}dz)   dw \\
&=& {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_C \hat{x}(w)(\int_C \hat{y}(v) v^{n-1}w^{n-1} dv)  dw \\
&=& {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_C \hat{x}(w)(\int_C \hat{y}(v) v^{n-1} dv)  w^{n-1}dw \\
&=& x(n)y(n)
\end{eqnarray}
Using the substitution $v={z \over w}$.